# Processing Video Frames in C# (FFMPEG Slow)

Tags: c#, performance, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to extract frames out of mp4 videos in order to process them.

Namely there is a watermark / timestamp within the video image which I want to use to automatically stitch the videos together. The Video creation date is not sufficient for this task.
[image]

Also the part of extracting the text out of the video with AI is fine.

However, FFMPEG seems terribly slow. the source Video is 1080p / 60fps (roughly 1GB per 5 Minutes of video).

I have tried two methods so far using Accord.FFMPEG wrapper:

```
public void GetVideoFrames(string path)
{
    using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
    {
        // open video file
        vFReader.Open(path);
        // counter is beeing used to extract every xth frame (1 Frame per second)
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount;i ++)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter <= 60)
            {
                _ = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap frame = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();
                // Process Bitmap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other attempt:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount;i+= 60)
{
    // notice here, I am specifying which exact frame to extract
    Bitmap frame = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame(i);
    // process frame
}
```

The second method is what I tried first and it's totally unfeasible. Apparently FFMPEG makes a new seek for each specific frame and thus the operation takes longer and longer for each frame processed.
After 5 frames already, it takes roughly 4 seconds to produce one Frame.

The first method at least does not seem to suffer from that issue as heavily but it still takes roughly 2 seconds to yield a frame. At this rate i'm faster to process the video manually.

Is there anything wrong with my approach? Also I rather don't want to have a solution where I need to separately install third party libraries on the target machine.
So, if there are any alternatives, I'd be happy to try them out but it seems litterally everyone on stack overflow is either pointing to ffmpeg or opencv.

Comment: Aren't you pulling every single frame as an image? Why do you expect it to be fast? When you say stitch videos together, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: no. Method 1 (faster) is indeed pulling every single frame, and dumping most of them. Of course its heck slow. That's why I used method 2 first, expecting that ffmpeg would seek from the last known position in the stream. But apparently, it seeks from position 0 every single time. So method 2 (should) not pull every single frame, but its way way slower.

Comment: You have to understand that whatever "ffmpeg" is here, is likely just a wrapper around the ffmpeg executable, and each time you execute a command it will launch a new instance of the ffmpeg executable.

Comment: By stitching videos together, I mean taking two videos, examining the frames of the videos, and create one video out of those two videos by rendering the videos together.

Comment: OK so you'll render them side-by-side or something after syncing them up?

Comment: A couple of years ago, I implemented such a functionality using DirectShow (custom filters written in C++). It was very fast. I think you should switch to native if you need performance.

Comment: yes in the end I will probably render them side by side. I might also let AI analyze the recorded videos, find interesting spots and render them into one "best of" video.

What you mention with the ffmpeg wrapper is correct. I have not found native alternatives yet.

Comment: dymanoid that is what i'm looking out for. Do you know any native alternatives or do you have any resources on mp4 encoding so I can build my own?

Comment: How many times do you need to check the timestamp? I mean, will individual videos have jumps such that you need to cut them into individual sections, and then sync them with another video with jumps? Or do you just need to find the first matching frame between them?

Comment: The timestamp is not visible at all times. Thats the main issue. If i have found it in one frame, I can calculate it programmatically for the whole clip and break the loop of frame extration.
The timestamp might only be visible at the end of the video or not at all (then the video gets dumped into trashbin)

Comment: You can use DirectShow or Media Foundation for that. These are Windows' native technologies. You don't need to bother with decoding video formats and stuff. This will be done by Windows for you. You can access the video frames data, seek through your videos, encode the videos back etc.

Comment: I think that dymanoid's suggestion is probably best for your use case then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem isn't with FFmpeg, but with the Accord wrapper doing the seek. I'd recommend using ffmpeg directly in a single pass to extract the frames, as it has options to extract only keyframes or every X frames (or you can just use the embedded video timestamps...). But if you want to continue with your path then maybe consider [passing the desired frame index](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Video_FFMPEG_VideoFileReader_ReadVideoFrame_2.htm) rather than a for loop - it should be faster, and maybe you can parrallelize it.

But it'll be ***much*** faster to do that all in a separate ffmpeg process.